# Multiplying a list and randomly re-assigning that list to a series of numbers

Tags: random, code-review

I'm trying to write a script that matches a particular element to a coordinate. Let's say there are 24 coordinates; and that fractionally a:b:c:d:e is 18%:18%:18%:18%:27%. Instead of matching 4 of a, b, c, and d to individual coordinates and e to the final 8 (to a sum of 24), I want to generate a list of 24 points from my initial list of a,b,c,d,e and those percentages and then randomly pair them to available coordinates.

The current code I'm using is below, is there an easier way to do this?

Inputs:

```
elements = Transpose[{{aa, bb, cc, dd, ee}}]
xelement = {0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.18};
spin = Transpose[{{"Spin=4", "Spin=3", "Spin=3", "Spin=2", 
 "Spin=2"}}];

PosFCC = {
{0.000000, 0.250000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.166667, 0.750000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.333333, 0.750000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.666667, 0.750000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.833333, 0.500000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.833333, 0.250000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.333333, 0.500000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.500000, 0.750000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.833333, 0.750000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.333333, 0.000000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.000000, 0.750000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.500000, 0.000000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.166667, 0.000000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.166667, 0.250000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.666667, 0.500000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.500000, 0.500000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.666667, 0.250000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.166667, 0.500000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.333333, 0.250000, 0.500000 }, 
{0.666667, 0.000000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.500000, 0.250000, 0.000000 }, 
{0.833333, 0.000000, 0.500000} 
};
```

Current Code:

```
pos1 = ArrayFlatten[{{elements, spin}}];
For[
  (i = 1) && (balance = 0) && (store = pos1),
  i < Dimensions[pos1][[1]] + 1,
  i++,
  (For[
     j = 1,
     j < (If[
        balance > 1.01,
        ((Round[xelement[[i]]*Dimensions[PosFCC][[1]]]) + 1),
        (Round[xelement[[i]]*Dimensions[PosFCC][[1]]])
        ]),
     j++,
     store = Insert[store, pos1[[i]], 1]
     ])
   &&
   (If[
     balance > 1.01,
     balance = 0, 
     balance = 
      balance + (xelement[[i]]*Dimensions[PosFCC][[1]] - 
         Round[xelement[[i]]*Dimensions[PosFCC][[1]]])
     ]
    )
  ];

pos2 = RandomSample[store];
pos3 = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[PosFCC], pos2[[All, 1]], 1]];
pos4 = Transpose[Insert[Transpose[pos3], pos2[[All, 2]], 5]];
posd = TableForm[pos4, TableSpacing -> {0, 5}];
```

Output:

```
bb     0.           0.25     0.5     Spin=3
dd     0.166667     0.75     0.      Spin=2
dd     0.333333     0.75     0.5     Spin=2
bb     0.666667     0.75     0.5     Spin=3
cc     0.833333     0.5      0.5     Spin=3
ee     0.833333     0.25     0.      Spin=2
aa     0.333333     0.5      0.      Spin=4
dd     0.5          0.75     0.      Spin=2
ee     0.833333     0.75     0.      Spin=2
bb     0.           0.       0.      Spin=3
aa     0.           0.5      0.      Spin=4
ee     0.333333     0.       0.      Spin=2
ee     0.           0.75     0.5     Spin=2
aa     0.5          0.       0.5     Spin=4
bb     0.166667     0.       0.5     Spin=3
bb     0.166667     0.25     0.      Spin=3
aa     0.666667     0.5      0.      Spin=4
cc     0.5          0.5      0.5     Spin=3
aa     0.666667     0.25     0.5     Spin=4
dd     0.166667     0.5      0.5     Spin=2
dd     0.333333     0.25     0.5     Spin=2
cc     0.666667     0.       0.      Spin=3
cc     0.5          0.25     0.      Spin=3
cc     0.833333     0.       0.5     Spin=3
```

Comment: Please provide more information and useful data in the question itself.

Comment: Edited with more info + code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RandomChoice`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RandomChoice.html) can take a list of weights, so you can do this:

```
Join[RandomChoice[xelement -> elements, 24], PosFCC, 2]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! that does exactly what I wanted it to do.

Comment: I realised that RandomChoice randomises the results without considering for limits. I couldn't find a random function that does that so I've updated the post with some code I've written that (I think) does that.

Answer (score 0):

```
elements = Transpose[{{Fe, Mn, Cu, Ni, Tc}}];
xelement = {0.3, 0.3, 0.15, 0.1, 0.15};
```

Introduce this:

```
names = {Fe, Mn, Cu, Ni, Tc};
```

Evaluating

```
names xelement
```

then gives

> ```
> {0.3 Fe, 0.3 Mn, 0.15 Cu, 0.1 Ni, 0.15 Tc}
> ```

and

```
RandomSample[names xelement]
```

gives

> ```
> {0.3 Mn, 0.15 Cu, 0.15 Tc, 0.1 Ni, 0.3 Fe}
> ```

The last part of your question I cannot understand. Could you reformulate it please?

Comment: Ah, I wanted to take those five items from elements and create up to 24 copies of them but they needed to be weighted according to xelement so they can be combined with the contents in PosFCC.

Comment: @Zhao in the resulting table in your question there are 8 different names of elements. Where do these come from? Could you please provide an example output that corresponds to your definitions? Also I do not see what you mean by "weighted according xelement". I cannot see what this is supposed to mean from your example output.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Apologies I suck at explaining >< - and I copy-pasted in from a wrong file. I'm trying to write a script that matches a particular element to a coordinate. Let's say there are 24 coordinates; and that fractionally a:b:c:d:e is 9%:9%:9%:9%:18%. Instead of matching 4 of a, b, c, and d to individual coordinates and e to the final 8 (to a sum of 24), I wanted to generate a list of 24 points from my initial list of a,b,c,d,e and those percentages and then randomly pair them to available coordinates. I know I can use shuffle for the last bit; initial bit's the problem.Eg output @ top